# Flip Menu with Fixed Top Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a doubt.

I need to implement a flip menu, but on the internet I found only examples using css transformations, and vendors prefix. But all examples show divs that are not fixed, and the css below have a fixed menu (copied and pasted code and reduce the net, is not very pretty) and when I have a menu and the approaches of put font and back divs don't work.

I need help with this. I need a way in which whole site (including the set menu) are replaced with other content (as a great turning of the page).

Example: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

I need a horizontal flip, and right horizontal flip.

Thank you so much.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BuHql

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="">SEO</a></li>
        <li><a href="">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Wordpress</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { height: 800px; background: black; }
.nav{ background: white; z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%;}

.nav { height: 42px; background: white;}
.nav ul { list-style: none; }
.nav ul li{float: left; margin-top: 6px; padding: 6px; border-right: 1px solid #ACACAC;}
.nav ul li:first-child{ padding-left: 0;}
.nav ul li a { }
.nav ul li a:hover{ text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is the question? Can you send a link to examples which show divs that are not fixed?

Comment: Example: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Comment: i dont see any attempt at implementing the flipping code

Comment: Is this a flipping what do you want http://jsfiddle.net/suska/VASX7/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this, in otherwise case, is using the following construction:

HTML:

```
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">Front content</div>
    <div class="back">Back content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Placing colors to facilitate understanding.*/
.front { background: green; }
.back { background: red; }

/*Add this class to a  ".flipper" element using the way that is well to you (using a    click, a hover or any other trigger).*/
 .flip {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    /*Add others vendors styles to more compatibility*/
}
/*Configuring the duration and the 3d mode of command*/
 .flipper {
    position: relative; /*relative is very important*/
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
}

/*Required for no appear both at the same time*/
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/*Causes the back start hidden (it is rotated 180 degrees, so it will not appear)*/
 .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/*Hide the rear face during the flip.*/
 .front, .back {
    position: relative; /*Again, the relative position is very important to work on any layout without crash.*/
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/*needed for webkit browsers understand what's in front and what is behind*/
body {
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

JS (jQuery) use example:

```
$('body').hover(function () {
    $('.flipper').addClass('flip');
});
$('body').click(function () {
    $('.flipper').removeClass('flip');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple jquery plugin that can help you achieving this effect.

You can find it here:
http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy//

It is easy to use and you can choose what kind of flip you want.  ;)